# Install MiKTeX packages copy/pasting

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I don't have admin rights, getting the repository online is blocked and are not allowed to bypass it and I cannot put a USB drive on my computer.
I do have MiKTeX installed (but basic so no package installed).

Because of all my limitations, the solution I found was to install LaTeX packages by simply using Copy/Paste on the packages.
A colleague gave me the files and folders of LaTeX packages and I copied it to `C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\`.
I then tested adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` in my `.tex`. I run `pdflatex document.tex` and get:

```bash
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>

(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*

(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg)
(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf))
(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel/locale/en\babel-english.tex)
(C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
```

And opens the message:

[image]

I understand I succeded in installing hyperref but not ltxcmds. However, the file `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\generic\ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty` exists.

How can I tell MiKTeX to look there? In MiKTeX console I already have ``C:\Users<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX` in **Settings -> Directories**

Any other solution will be great.

Comment: Can you visit ctan? You can download zipped files from there, Unzip them in your directory and all will be fine.

Comment: I could but I cannot download them all right? That is why a colleague that already downloaded a bunch of them was my fastest solution. I can go, however, to [ltxcmds](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds) but the zip does not have any `sty` file inside. Now provided I downloaded it, where should I copy it's content? In `tex/latex` or `tex/generic`?

Comment: if the file is really already there try to update the file name database (in the miktex console in the menu tasks). (And check if you really have ltxcmds.sty, look for hidden extensions!)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was that I should not put it in
`C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\generic\ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty`
but in
`C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\texmf\tex\generic\ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty`

I just doubled my `tex` folder in a new `texmf` folder. I have everything twice, very optimized, bit it works.

You can check where the package should go using the *MiKTeX Console* and going to *Packages*, select the package you want, then *info* and go to the *Files* tab.

Comment: that sounds definitively wrong, as according to your log hyperref is in \Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/. And on my machine the file is in `AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty`.

Comment: Indeed, now I have problems with glossaries and it does not work... using neither of both paths... this installs seems quite broken